# Using a variable for amount in Stripe Payment Gateway

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe payment onto my site. I have a php variable '$val' set with a price amount sent from a form

```
$val = $_POST['myFieldName'];
```

I'm trying to use this variable to charge the amount it holds with stripe

```
 Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                             "amount" =>  $val ,
                            "currency" => "gbp",
                            "card" => $_POST['stripeToken']));
```

But it seems Stripe wont except this variable. it puts a 'Missing required param: amount' error on the page It only wants to accept a actuale integer such as '1234' I tried cast to int using => intval($var) nut with no joy. Could someone tell me where Im going wrong

Thnks

Comment: Set up your error_reporting correctly, then most likely PHP will tell you.

Comment: sorry how do you meam

Comment: What price are you trying? The price should be in cents - e.g 500 for $5, or 499 for $4.99 - You cant use $ symbol or decimals.

Comment: hi the $ is part of the php variable

Comment: Sorry, I mean - if you were to give me an example of what is in the myFieldName input, what would I see? Does the input contain 499 or 4.99 or $4.99 etc?... Hope this makes sense?

Comment: it contains the price multiplied by 100 to convert to cents as you mention so something like 5430

Comment: ok, and if you do a die((int)$val); does this contain the number you would expect? To debug, I would add the array as a separate variable and call like this: `$data = array("amount" => (int)$val, "currency" => "gbp", "card" => $_POST['stripeToken']);` then `print_r($data);` just to see that the data looks as we expect it to look - can you try this and post the output please so I can see? (hide the token of course!)

Comment: i tried but it wouldn't print the $data variable. using (int)$val instead of just $val gives me a 'Invalid positive integer' stripe error on page

Comment: Have you verified that  `$_POST['myFieldName']` actually has a value in it and isn't null || empty? Also, make sure you are multiplying the amount * 100 at some point to convert it to cents.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 400,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "card" => "tok_14igbg2eZvKYlo2Cm0Akcrhg", // obtained with Stripe.js
  "description" => "Charge for test@example.com"
));
```

`description` field is missing as per the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue but its my coding fault
when you land on payment page 
in the end just add this line before form submit button
" name="myFieldName">